# How to match 2 arrays and get an output in new array Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say i have 2 arrays with the same length filled with integers

```
a = [6,3,5,1]
b = [6,2,5,3]
```

And i want to compare these arrays and get an output in new (c) array so it would look like this

```
c = [+,-,+,-]
```

If there will be 0 matches then my new array would give `[-,-,-,-]` and vice versa in case of 4 matches `[+,+,+,+]`

Comment: `[+,-,+,-]` isn't valid Ruby syntax. What kind of objects should the new array contain – strings, symbols or maybe booleans?

Answer (score 1):

```rb
a.each_with_index.map {|x, i| b[i] == x ? '+' : '-'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Array.html#zip-method) to get pairs from both arrays which can then be converted via [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Enumerable.html#map-method), e.g.:

```
a.zip(b).map { |i, j| i == j }
#=> [true, false, true, false]
```

to get `"+"` and `"-"` instead you'd use:

```
a.zip(b).map { |i, j| i == j ? '+' : '-' }
#=> ["+", "-", "+", "-"]
```